# Get access token for twitter application hosted on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I want to get a Twitter access token via a web form hosted on Google app engine. I wrote a python code to do so. While it runs fairly well on the terminal on my local machine, it is giving an error when I deploy it on Google App engine sdk.

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code for the same is :

```
import sys
import requests,sys
sys.path.insert(0,'requests_oauthlib')
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs

REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"

CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXX"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXX"

OAUTH_TOKEN = ""
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ""

def setup_oauth():
    """Authorize your app via identifier."""
    # Request token

    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    r = requests.post(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)

    resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    resource_owner_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    # Authorize
    authorize_url = AUTHORIZE_URL + resource_owner_key
    print 'Please go here and authorize: ' + authorize_url

    verifier = raw_input('Please input the verifier: ')
    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
                   client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                   resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                   verifier=verifier)

    # Finally, Obtain the Access Token
    r = requests.post(url=ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
    credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
    token = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

    return token, secret

def get_oauth():
    oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY,
                client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                resource_owner_key=OAUTH_TOKEN,
                resource_owner_secret=OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    return oauth
```

The `setup_oauth` is called from the post method of the class where the user is redirected after clicking the button.

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~twitterlookback/2.374658065002598509/testing.py", line 86, in post
    token, secret = setup_oauth()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~twitterlookback/2.374658065002598509/testing.py", line 43, in setup_oauth
    resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Now if I do `dir(credentials)` I get this as output

```
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
```

which clearly has `__getitem__`. I don't get why it is showing the error still.

Comment: @TimHoffman but it works fine on local machine

Comment: Yes it may well work because you call returns something that allows [] access.  But you aren't checking what comes back from the call.  You will be missing something in your auth dance with twitter.

Comment: Why isn't it working on Google App engine? Even though the credentials is returning something which has __getitem__ .

Comment: Look what I have written below and at the code, its the result of `credentials.get('oauth_token')` that you are trying to call `__getitem__` on not on `credentials`

Comment: @TimHoffman what changes should I do in order to make the code work?

Comment: How about doing some basic debugging, start looking at each step of the with process, examine what is in r.content for starters

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error is because you are trying to call `__getitem___` on the result of calling `credentials.get('oauth_token')` which is `None` not a list.

You should always check what is returned from calls like this, rather than assuming you got the expected result, or wrap it in a try block.

Answer (score 0):

Google App engine does not receive instructions like:
    verifier = raw_input('Please input the verifier: ')
because is a web platform not a shell.
It is necesary to have a way to enter information in a httprequest httpresponse way.
"verifier" can be inputted to your appliation by using webapp, django, etc.